# Storing highscore in database efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, architecture

How can i store a highscore efficiently in database?

I have a table player_score with two columns player_id (primary key), score (integer value).

Now i want the position of a player in the highscore and i created the following query

```
SELECT player_score.player_id,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player_score ps WHERE ps.score >= player_score.score) AS position   
FROM player_score      
WHERE player_score.player_id = 19
```

I think this is very inefficiently have you any other ideas? It is also conceivable to use elasticsearch or any other technology to store this data efficiently.

Comment: I think it's OK. You can change instead of COUNT(*) put COUNT(id). Add index on score field

Comment: My test with 1 Mio of entries had a runtime of 240ms on local machine. I think it´s okay. I will store the values in memcache to get more performance. Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the exact position of a user in the high scores list:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS pos
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM player_score
      ORDER BY score DESC) AS ordered_scores, player_score
WHERE player_score.player_id=3 AND player_score.score < ordered_scores.score;
```